# Error after getting new scrape information facebook debug tools

Tags: facebook, drupal-7

I tried scraping the data from my page using the facebook debug tools and it works fine, no signs of error or warnings.. but when i clicked the button fetch new scrape information that's how I got the error.

When posting in facebook it is okay, so I wast just wondering why this error is appearing after button click of get new scrape information..

Thanks in advance...

[image]

Comment: Does the FB user with id `121790674546188` exists?

Comment: I see. the id that should be there is user id right? not page id? thanks a lot for opening my mind.

Comment: It should be the user id